# syntax for passing array to annotation

Tags: java, arrays, annotations, arguments, argument-passing

A few days ago I was forced to use the following construction for my class declaration:

```
@Table(name="UserPattern",  uniqueConstraints={
   @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"user_id", "patern_id"})
})
```

I was very surprised by this syntax.

Usually I thought that if I should to pass array to annotation O I should write the following:

```
declared_inside_annotation_name={value1,value2...}
```

but in this case it looks like the following:

```
uniqueConstraints={
                    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"user_id", "patern_id"})
                  }
```

`@Table` annotation declaration:

```
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Table {

    String name() default "";


    String catalog() default "";


    String schema() default "";


    UniqueConstraint[] uniqueConstraints() default { };


    Index[] indexes() default {};
}
```

please clarify this syntax.

Comment: Could you point a difference between your expected notation of `declared_inside_annotation_name={value1,value2...}` and actual `uniqueConstraints={single_value}`?

Comment: instead of value1,value2 I see @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={value1,value2})

Comment: You confuse the `@Table.uniqueConstraints`, which is an array of `@UniqueConstraint`s and contains a single item, with the value `@UniqueConstraint.columnNames`, which belongs to another object and is an array of strings and contains two items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually not a conflict between your expected syntax from your `declared_inside_annotation_name` example and the syntax from the `@Table` annotation. The type of elements for an array property of an annotation does not necessarily have to be a string (which might be what you have expected). It may actually be another annotation.

This is the case with the `uniqueConstraints` property of the `@Table` annotation. If you check the declaration of the `UniqueConstraint` class, you see that it is an annotation itself. When writing it down, you use the usual `@AnnotationTypeName` notation.

Comment: Thus **@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"user_id", "patern_id"})** one array element ?